# How to make a process ring with fork and pipe?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, child-process

Currently I'm learning C and I'd like to make a **ring of *n* childs** process with forks and pipes where ***n*** is a number enter in argument, each child could communicate with the next child in one direction [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB1gl.png.)
I tried to do it where each child send to the next child its pid but I don't get what I want for instance if I create 3 childs :

1. PID:1,i in loop : 0, received : 0
2. PID:2, i in loop : 1, received : 0
3. PID:3, i in loop : 2, received : 0

But I should get :

1. PID:1,i in loop : 0, received : 3
2. PID:2, i in loop : 1, received : 1
3. PID:3, i in loop : 2, received : 2

Sometimes I receive a value from one random child to another here is my code, I'm not really comfortable with multiples pipes in a loop.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>              
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    if(argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s <integer> [> 2]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int number_process = atoi(argv[1]);
    if(number_process < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s <integer> [> 2]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Création de %d processus pour une élection : \n", number_process);
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    int * t = (int *) malloc((2 * number_process) * sizeof(int));

    for(k = 0; k < number_process; k++) {
        pipe(&t[2*i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < number_process; i++) {
        if(fork() == 0) {
            for(j = 0; j < number_process*2; j++) {
                if(j != 2*i && j != ((2*i+3)%(number_process*2))) {
                    close(t[j]);
                }
            }
            close(t[(2*i+1)%(number_process*2)]);
            close(t[((2*i+2)%(number_process*2))]);

            int pid = (int) getpid();
            write(t[(2*i+3)%(number_process*2)], &pid, sizeof(int));

            int in = 0;
            read(t[i*2], &in, sizeof(int));
            printf("%d : %d\n", in, getpid()); 

            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the code is wrong?

Comment: I tested it with printf where the i, the current process id and the received integer is displayed and I should get the previous pid on each child but I don't get what I should get.

Comment: Add to the question what you think you should get and what you actually do get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the problems I have found in the program:

1. No error checking.  Without error checking, it is much harder to find the other errors.  Note that `read()` will return a negative result if an error occurs.  In this case, you will probably get `EBADF` from `read()`.
2. Once you add the error checking, you would investigate the source of the `EBADF` error, and notice that the pipes are not initialized correctly.  This is due to the line `pipe(&t[2*i]);` which should use `k` instead of `i`.  Another way to find this error is by using the address sanitizer or Valgrind, both of which would have found the error immediately (without having to change your code at all).  Scoping loop variables inside the loops would have also found this problem immediately, so use `for (int i = 0; ...)` instead of `int i; for (i = ; ...)`.
3. The `close()` function is called twice after the end of a loop on files which are already closed.  This error is innocuous, however.
4. The parent process should wait for its children to exit, and it should also close the pipes first.
5. The program relies on line-buffering in order to work correctly.  A good solution is to `fflush(stdout)` before calling `fork()`.

Here is an updated version with notes:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>              
#include <unistd.h>

void usage(const char *prog) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s <integer> [> 2]\n", prog);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    if(argc != 2) {
        usage(argv[0]);
    }

    int number_process = atoi(argv[1]);
    if(number_process < 2) {
        usage(argv[0]);
    }

    printf("Création de %d processus pour une élection : \n", number_process);
    // Flush stdout before fork.
    fflush(stdout);

    // Do not cast the result of malloc
    // Use sizeof(*pipes) instead of sizeof(int)
    // Prefer descriptive variable names
    int *pipes = malloc((2 * number_process) * sizeof(*pipes));
    if (!pipes) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Scope loop variables in the loop
    for (int i = 0; i < number_process; i++) {
        int r = pipe(&pipes[2*i]);
        if (r == -1) {
            perror("pipe");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < number_process; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
            // Let's avoid copy/pasting 2*i and (2*i+3)%(number_process*2)
            // everywhere, which is hard to read
            int infd = pipes[2*i];
            int outfd = pipes[(2*i+3)%(number_process*2)];
            for (int j = 0; j < number_process*2; j++) {
                if (pipes[j] != infd && pipes[j] != outfd) {
                    close(pipes[j]);
                }
            }

            int self = getpid();
            ssize_t amt;
            amt = write(outfd, &self, sizeof(int));
            if (amt == -1) {
                perror("write");
                exit(1);
            }

            int in;
            ssize_t r = read(pipes[i*2], &in, sizeof(int));
            if (r == -1) {
                perror("read");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("%d : %d\n", in, (int)getpid()); 

            exit(0);
        }
    }
    // Close pipes and wait for children to finish
    for (int i = 0; i < number_process * 2; i++) {
        close(pipes[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < number_process; i++) {
        wait(NULL);
    }

    // Return at end of main() is implicitly "return 0".
}
```

Comment: Thank you I'll take a look tomorrow and come back to you if I have any questions !